# How do I insert an Excel sheet or CSV into Google Sheets using pygsheets (with or without Pandas)?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pygsheets

I have some data in an Excel sheet, I need to programmatically be able to insert it into a Google Sheet via a short python script. I'm using pygsheets and pandas (if I need it). I have the auth stuff set up and I'm able to access the sheet I want to insert data into; it's just the actual insertion using pygsheets I'm having issues with. Here's some code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pygsheets
import pandas as pd
import json

# set settings file
settings_file = open("/Users/user/Desktop/settings.json", "r").read()
settings = json.loads(settings_file)
creds = settings['oauth_creds']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(creds)
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
)

# set dataframe as excel sheet (saved on Desktop)
new_data = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Desktop/test-data.xlsx', None)

# instantiate pygsheets with credentials
gc = pygsheets.authorize(custom_credentials=scoped_credentials)

# open spreadsheet with URL
sheet_url = settings['sheet_url']
sh = gc.open_by_url(sheet_url)

# activate correct sheet
sheet_name = settings['data_sheet']
wks = sh.worksheet_by_title(sheet_name)

# empty active sheet
wks.clear()

# add dataframe to active sheet
wks.set_dataframe(new_data,(1,1))
```

When I run the script, I get an error on the last line: `AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'replace'`. Any idea how to properly send data to the Sheet? Also, if it's easier, I can do this with a CSV; I also do not have to use pandas, if it's easier without it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I've temporarily solved my issue by pulling the data from a CSV: `with open('/Users/user/Desktop/test-data.csv', 'rU') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  new_data = list(reader)` and then using `wks.append_table(values=new_data)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Generate credential](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html) file using Google sheets and name it as `creds.json`:

1. [Enable API Access](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#enable-api-access) for a Project if you haven’t done it yet.
2. Go to “APIs & Services > Credentials” and choose “Create credentials > Service account key”.
3. Fill out the form
4. Click “Create key”
5. Select “JSON” and click “Create”

then try:

```
import pygsheets
def upload_to_gsheet(df, sheet_number):
    gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=/path/to/creds.json)
    sh = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
    wks = sh[sheet_number]
    wks.set_dataframe(df, (1, 1))
```